# Android Studio corrupt gradle build error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error:
[image: Gradle build error]

I have tried deleting the .gradle file from my project root.  I have also tried using an older copy of the project.  I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting the gradle cache located at C:\Users\.gradle\caches\
Hope this helps someone else.
Cheers!